# Docker container volume has root only access

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-volume

I am trying to start containers as non root user. The volume which is being generated has root only access. The non root user of container is unable to write in the volume directory of the container.

docker-compose.yml

```
  volumes:
       - ./trm/workspace:/opt/kad/translation/workspace
```

Dockerfile:

```
RUN chown -R nonrootuser /opt/kad/translation/workspace
VOLUME /opt/kad/translation-resource-monitor/workspace
```

Is there any way to create the volume with write access to non root user.

Comment: Show the Dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

Volumes are not generated but mounted with host privileges. Also Dockerfile directives are executed on image build which is before you run a container. In your case `/opt/kad/translation/workspace` directory owned by `nonrootuser` user is being replaced by `./trm/workspace` owned by the same uid/gid as on the host when container is started. So you need to make sure the host folder has correct permissions before running the container, e. g:

```
chown -R uid_of_nonrootuser_in_container:gid_of_nonrootuser_in_container \
  ./trm/workspace && docker-compose up -d
```

Note that there are different users on host and in container so you should use uid and gid of the container user, not it's username and group name. To find uid and gid run `id nonrootuser` in container.

Another solution (as Manish Joshi pointed out) is to make the directory writable for all users:

```
chmod -R 0777 ./trm/workspace
```

But it gives you less control of the folder's security.

Comment: This could spell trouble in automating this process... it would make it non-portable as well to some extent. It would be easier if you could mount a directory in host to container which could be given read+write+execute access to other's or may be say 777 permission.

Comment: Thanks @dizeee, that helped.